# Integral with possibly partial fraction

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve $\int \frac{x+1}{x^2+3}dx$. How would I do it? If I had $x^2+3$ in denominator I would proceed to look for A and B in $\int \frac{x+1}{x^2-3}dx=\int \frac{A}{x-\sqrt{3}}+\frac{B}{x+\sqrt{3}}$, but I don't know how to procced in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\dfrac{d(x^2+3)}{dx}=2x,$

$$\frac{x+1}{x^2+3}=\frac12\frac{2x}{x^2+3}+\frac B{x^2+3}$$

Comment: would you mind explaining a bit why you are taking derivative? a link to some website about this 'technique' would suffice. thank you

Comment: @cgnx, So, $$\int\frac{2x}{x^2+3} dx=\int\frac{d(x^2+3)}{x^2+3}=\ln|x^2+3|+K$$